# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'params') sveltkit

Tags: sveltekit

i just upgrade svelte migration route then create +page.js file this script

```js
export async function load({ page }) {
   var songId = page.params.songId;
   const itunesSearched = await fetch(
    `https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=${songId}&entity=song`
  );
  var res = await itunesSearched.json();
  var songResults = res.results[0];
  return {songResults}
}
```

**Error below**

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'params')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'params')
    at load (/src/routes/[searched]/[songId]/+page.js:2:22)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the interface of the event data [in the docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/types#sveltejs-kit-loadevent). It has no `page` property; `params` are a direct property of the event, so you should be able to just destructure that:

```js
export async function load({ params }) { ...
```